# Split group of special characters from string

Tags: python

In test.txt:

```
quiet confidence^_^
want:P
(:let's start
```

Codes:

```
import re
file  = open('test.txt').read()
for line in file.split('\n'):
    line = re.findall(r"[^\w\s$]+|[a-zA-z]+|[^\w\s$]+", line)
    print " ".join(line)
```

Results showed:

```
quiet confidence^_^
want : P
(: let ' s start
```

I tried to separate group of special characters from string but still incorrect. 
Any suggestion?

Expected results:

```
quiet confidence ^_^
want :P
(: let's start
```

Comment: Why do you expect the `:P` to be together and not separated as `: P`? And why wouldn't the apostrophe in `let's` be separated?

Comment: Rather than `file  = open('test.txt').read()\nfor line in file.split('\n'):`, I'd recommend `with open('test.txt') as file:\n\tfor line in file:` and then stripping off any newlines. This will make your code more efficient for large files and will automatically close the file if any errors occur.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as @interjay said, you must define what you consider a word and what is "special characters". Still I would use 2 separate regexes to find what a word is and what is not.

```
word = re.compile("[a-zA-Z\']+")
not_word = re.compile("[^a-zA-Z\']+")

for line in file.split('\n'):
    matched_words = re.findall(word, line)
    non_matching_words = re.findall(not_word, line)
    print " ".join(matched_words)
    print " ".join(non_matching_words)
```

Have in mind that spaces `\s+` will be grouped as non words.